# Show up text field for state in woocommerce for specific countries

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

There are some countries in woocommerce where the State field is not visible at all, and i would like to be able to show them up on specific countries as a required text field.

I tried a few solutions i found in here but they all seem to be old posts or at least i could not make them work.

I found two very similar versions of the same snipet, one throws a bunch of errors on the checkout page, and the other is the one above, that simply does not work, it adds the text field for shipping on all countries and not just in france:

```
function xa_filter_woocommerce_states( $states ) { 
    unset( $states['FR'] );
    var_dump( $states ) ;
    return $states;
};
add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', 'xa_filter_woocommerce_states', 10, 1 );

function xa_filter_woocommerce_get_country_locale( $locale ) { 
    $locale['FR']['state']['required'] = true;
    return $locale; 
};
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_country_locale', 'xa_filter_woocommerce_get_country_locale', 10, 1 );
```

This is working fine, it does what i need, but it throws some text (does not seem to be errors) onto the checkout page as in:

array(76) { ["AF"]=> array(0) { } ["AO"]=> array(18) { ["BGO"]=> string(5) "Bengo" ["BLU"]=> string(8) "Benguela" ["BIE"]=> string(4) "Bié" ["CAB"]=> string(7) "Cabinda" ["CNN"]=> string(6) "Cunene" ["HUA"]=> string(6) "Huambo" ["HUI"]=> string(6) "Huíla" ["CCU"]=> string(14) "Kuando Kubango" ["CNO"]=> string(12) "Kwanza-Norte" ["CUS"]=> string(10) "Kwanza-Sul" ["LUA"]=> string(6) "Luanda" ["LNO"]=> string(11) "Lunda-Norte" ["LSU"]=> string(9)

Answer (score 0):

I found the code above works just fine, and the "errors" on screen are no errors, but a dump from a variable. So, removing 1 line of the above code, does the trick:

```
function xa_filter_woocommerce_states( $states ) { 
    unset( $states['FR'] );
    return $states;
};
add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', 'xa_filter_woocommerce_states', 10, 1 );

function xa_filter_woocommerce_get_country_locale( $locale ) { 
    $locale['FR']['state']['required'] = true;
    return $locale; 
};
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_country_locale', 'xa_filter_woocommerce_get_country_locale', 10, 1 );
```